# Distribute windows app from my own server

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I have developed a Window 10 app using Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app. i just want to distribute it from my own server. i don't want to put it on window store. is it possible? if yes, how can i?

Comment: You certainly can put an executable program on your server with a download link. Or, you can use any number of on-line stores. Note that you *should* cryptographically sign your application program *(with a developer key purchased from Microsoft)* so that users can trust that what they've downloaded is authentic.

Comment: I will put the zip file (Package). at device will download that package and install automatically when I will put any new build there, Manually I can do it, but now i need to automatically

Comment: Since installation often requires Administrator privileges, maybe an alternative approach would be to have your application merely ping the server to be informed that a new update is available. You can present the user with a hyperlink to download the latest installer. (I suggest that the installation process itself should be a proper installer, not a zip-file.) *Automatic* updates might run afoul of security-policies at customer sites. The running user might not be authorized to apply any update, and the application's files should be read-only.

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent, what the Windows Store already offers?

Comment: I have windows IOT core devices that will run at different locations, so I need to update my application on all these devices automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> I have windows IOT core devices that will run at different locations, so I need to update my application on all these devices automatically.

For the scenario of IoT core devices, a common easy way is to use the MDM system, aka. [Windows 10 Mobile and mobile device management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/windows-10-mobile-and-mdm?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> The MDM client allows the MDM system to configure policy settings; deploy apps and updates; and perform other management tasks, such as remotely wiping the device.

But this is often be used for company apps, using this means you need to become a partner of Microsoft, so this method is not suitable for personal development.

Another method is that you need to for example check the version of your app in your server and manually [Install Universal Windows Apps with the WinAppDeployCmd tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt203806.aspx), using this tool can deploy a Universal Windows app from a Windows 10 machine to any Windows 10 Mobile device. But your server should establish connections to target devices before.

You can also refer to the blog: [Just released: Windows 10 Application Deployment tool](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/09/just-released-windows-10-application-deployment-tool/) to get started.